# Netlify: How to run build tasks in serial?

Tags: static-site, hugo, netlify

I am having trouble getting my Hugo site to deploy with Netlify. I want to compile my static assets (Sass and JS) using Webpack before deployment and I am generating hashes for cache busting that hugo needs to read before generating the pages. Therefore `yarn run build` needs to finish running before `hugo` is invoked. However this does not appear to be happening judging from the Netlify deployment logs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

disclaimer:  I work for netlify.

Jessica's answer is almost certainly better for your use case, but in general, if folks aren't using tools like gulp/grunt/make (options in the build environment are "anything you can run on linux" mostly - see https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/18/how-our-build-bots-build-sites/), you can just chain commands together:

```
yarn run build && hugo
```

Make sure to use "&&" to chain commands - this will not only run them serially, it will also ensure that a problem in yarn run build will cause the build to be marked as a failure, rather than running hugo anyway and potentially publishing a broken build as would happen if you use

```
yarn run build ; hugo
```

Comment: `yarn run build && hugo` is the exact command I have but I am still encountering the problem described above.

Comment: @ErikBerkun-Drevnig then something else is likely wrong.  Sorry I didn't see this til now but Support can help debug this.

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that the Webpack tasks called by `yarn run build` complete before calling `hugo`, I recommend adding a pipeline build tool, like Gulp. The [Victor Hugo boilerplate](https://github.com/netlify/victor-hugo) uses exactly this setup. Excerpted, it looks like this:

In package `package.json`, the `build` command is defined to call `gulp build`:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "gulp build",
    ...
  }
```

This triggers `gulpfile.babel.js`, which defines the `build` task as a set of three sub-tasks, in order:

```
gulp.task("build", ["css", "js", "hugo"]);
```

Those sub-tasks are also defined in the gulpfile. In this case, `css` is defined to run PostCSS, and `js` to run Webpack. You would define these to match your asset pipeline, importing whatever plugins you need at the top of the file.

For the `hugo` task, Victor Hugo includes the Hugo binary directly in the repo, which aids portability. Alternatively, you could follow [this example](https://github.com/joranquinten/gulp-hugo/blob/master/Gulpfile.js#L156) and use the `gulp-shell` plugin to run the `hugo` command in the shell.

Comment: I would also ask why you think you need cachebusting.  Unless you change the caching directives by overriding our defaults, Netlify handles cache invalidation for you and does a really good job of it.  https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/02/23/better-living-through-caching/ describes how.

Comment: I think this is the better solution/answer, because it does not limit the shell you use in the case of windows users for development.

Comment: @fool can you explain what you mean by cachebusting in this case

Comment: @talves i was referring to what the OP mentioned, something like https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting/.  Netlify does some things to make this unnecessary:  https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/02/23/better-living-through-caching/